# SSH connection in a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, qprocess

I have a Qt application in C++ that runs on a Windows host and has to execute some commands via SSH in a Linux machine.

I tried everything that came to my mind but without a single success:

1. `QProcess()`, using both `ssh <user>@<address> "command"` and `cmd /c "ssh <user>@<address> \"command\""` did nothing, `powershell` same story.
2. Same story using the `system()`.
3. I tried both previous solutions with `runas /user:Administrator` but, again, nothing changed.
4. I embedded the SSH command in a bat file and tried with previous solutions. Same story.

In general, when using directly `ssh` I don't get any output and it doesn't run; when I prepend `cmd /c` (or `powershell`) I get:

> ssh is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch file

I know that I could use `libssh` or `libssh2` but it's been asked me to try to avoid them, so I'll use them only if there's no other options.

Some snippet that I tried using:

1. `QProcess`:

   ```
   QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
   proc->start("ssh", {"<user>@<address>",  "\"<command>\""}); 
   proc->waitForFinished();
   QString str = proc->readAll();
   std::cout << "out: "+ QString::number(proc->exitCode()) + " -- " + str;
   ```
2. same as before but with full *ssh.exe* path
3. same but with

   ```
   proc->start("cmd", {"/c", "ssh", "<user>@<address>",  "\"<command>\""});
   ```
4. `system()`:

   ```
   int ret = system("cmd /c \"ssh -t <user>@<address> \\\"<command>\\\"\"");
   std::cout()<<"ret: " + QString::number(ret));
   ```

   here I tried with all kind of `\` escape possible.

EDIT:
Ok, I might have found something.. Basically when I launch the command from my application, the OpenSSH folder containing ssh.exe is "missing". If I `dir` in `c:\Windows\System32`, I see everything except for the OpenSSH folder. If I run the same thing from CMD, the folder is present and contains ssh.exe
Do you have any ideas on how to access the folder with my application?

Comment: Show the complete not working example, with includes, main function, signal-slot connections if any, and event loop execution. `proc->start(...)` should work, but maybe will not do what you expect it to do. Take a look how to run command through ssh https://superuser.com/a/8687/916903

Comment: "did nothing" is a useless diagnostic. You should start by increasing the verbosity of ssh by adding `-v` (or multiple `-v`'s). I would not be surprised if it is stuck on the prompt for accepting the host key.

Comment: Anything involving `ssh -t` is a non-starter for the simple `QProcess` library: it does not do terminal emulation. Likewise, adding `cmd /c` will not make a difference here. You are simply constructing a commandline that `cmd` will immediately break apart again. The first form should be sufficient **if your ssh command ever terminates**

Comment: You should move away from `readAll` and listen what the `readyReadStandardOutput` and `readyReadStandardError` signals produce instead.

Comment: For "did nothing" I mean that there is no output (even separating output and error) and in terminates with an error and the exit code is 0.

Comment: The code in point 1. is the one i'm trying to run. No matter what command I try to run via SSH, it always crash. If I use cmd instead (like in 3.), I get "ssh is not recognized"

Comment: @Ravazz You state `"... terminates with an error"`: what error?  Also `"No matter what command I try to run via SSH, it always crash"`: how -- segfault, exception or what?  Sorry, but you need to show the real code (preferably in the form of a [mcve]) and describe, in detail, the errors/problems you encountered.